# Java String array: how do I check if the array has a value?

Tags: java, arrays, string, compare

I'm making a program in java that will use a string array say:

```
String[] category = new String[46];
```

Then I will check if the array in a for loop if it already has a value,

```
for(int checking = 21; checking <= 45 ;checking++) {
    if(category[checking]=INSERT_HERE) {
        textArea += category[checking] + "\n";
    }
}
```

What do I put in INSERT_HERE? Note: textArea is a named `JTextArea`.

Comment: A string variable without a value assigned is `null`, so check if it is *not* that. `if(category[checking] != null)`.

Comment: you can use `if(category[checking]!=null)`

Comment: category[checking]=INSERT_HERE is wrong.. '=' means assign. '==' means compare..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making a check if the value is not null, then use

```
if(category[checking]!=null)
```

And if you are making a check for some particular value, then

```
if(category[checking].equals(PARTICULAR_VALUE))
```

PS: '=' is for assignment, you should use '==' for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int checking=21;checking<=45;checking++) {
    if(category[checking] != null || category[checking] != "") {
       textArea += category[checking] +"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: if(category[checking] != null || category[checking].trim() != "")
        {
           textArea += category[checking].trim() +"\n";
        } //the trim() is safer

Comment: Shouldn't the || be &&? or better still `category[checking] != null && !category[checking].isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

u have to checkout if it is not null use like this:

```
 if(category[checking] != null) // will check all filled values only
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your array as

```
String[] category=new String[46];
```

you allocate 46 reference slots in memory for your array. These slots are initially `null`, so when you need to do a comparison like the one you asked, you need to check against `null`.

```
...
if(category[checking] != null)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that in your code:

```
for(int checking=21;checking<=45;checking++) {
    if(category[checking] != null) {
        textArea+=category[checking] +"\n";
    }
}
```

Or like that:

```
for(int checking=21;checking<=45;checking++) {
    if(category[checking] != "") {
        textArea+=category[checking] +"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: In your second example, comparing a String to another String with a != would not work, .equals(String) should be used to compare Strings.

Comment: OK!
Thanks for checking)